# Alarm is not displayed for lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, domino-designer-eclipse

I am setting the below properties of the document but still the alarm is not getting displayed. please help.

```
doc1.replaceItemValue("$AlarmUnit","M" );
doc1.replaceItemValue("$Alarm", 1);
doc1.replaceItemValue("$AlarmOffset", -30);
doc1.replaceItemValue("$AlarmMemoOptions", "");
doc1.replaceItemValue("Alarms", "1");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the document into the Folder ($Alarms). That is where the Client- Daemon searches for Alarms.

`doc1.PutInFolder("($Alarms)" )` should do the trick.

Be aware: Alarms only work in the mailfile that is configured in your location document!

Additional Information: In your code an item called `$AlarmTime` is also missing. Alternatively you could fill: `DueDateTime` (if it is a task) or `CalendarDateTime`

Just check the first column in the $Alarms- Folder for exact usage.

Comment: Thank u Torsten for the quick reply. I have tried the way u told but not getting alarm. but when i edit the document in lotus notes manually by setting time in "Notify me" its working fine.

Comment: You are most probably missing a Date- Time- Item... check my edits